# Windows Azure Authentication Provider is not enabled

Tags: android, azure

I'm developing an Android app with eclipse and using the Windows Azure Mobile Services as a BaaS and when I try to use authentication provider (of Google or Microsoft) from Android SDK provided by Microsoft, it always appears me the following error:

> com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException:
>   Logging in with the selected authentication provider is not enabled

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which Android Sdk are you targeting .. I think it must be 4.2 .

Comment: Ya. Which difference does it do?

Comment: its not support lower then 4.2

Comment: Oh, you're right but it is 4.2. I forgot to say that in the beginning it was working and in the next day it wasn't. It's weird

Comment: its horrible .... :-p lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem! :P

There was a missing configuration line in *AndroidManifest.xml* file which was the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I don't know how this happened, but maybe I removed without noticing it. Thanks [Akhilesh Mani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1706233/akhilesh-mani) for the attempt on helping me. But it is helpful anyway. ;)