# Azure Movile Services: Provider not enabled

Tags: android, authentication, azure

I'm using Azure Mobile Services in my android application to add authentication to the app, via Facebook and Google. However, every single time I attempt to login from the app, I receive the following error:

> "com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Logging >in with the selected authentication provider is not enabled".

No other errors occur. This is my code:

```
private void authenticate(boolean bRefreshCache)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    bAuthenticating = true;
    if (bRefreshCache || !loadUserTokenCache(mClient)) {
        mClient.login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook,
                new UserAuthenticationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(MobileServiceUser user,
                            Exception exception,
                            ServiceFilterResponse response) {

                        synchronized (mAuthenticationLock) {
                            if (exception == null) {
                                cacheUserToken(mClient.getCurrentUser());
                                Log.i("MappingRoadConditions",
                                        "authenticating");
                                createAndShowDialog(String.format(
                                        "You are now logged in - %1$2s",
                                        user.getUserId()), "Success");

                            } else {
                                createAndShowDialog(exception.getMessage(),
                                        "Login Error");
                            }
                            bAuthenticating = false;
                            mAuthenticationLock.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }
                });
    } else {
        // Other threads may be blocked waiting to be notified when
        // authentication is complete.
        synchronized (mAuthenticationLock) {
            bAuthenticating = false;
            mAuthenticationLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

The function for logging in by Google is exactly the same, other than the name of the provider of course.

1) I have tried troubleshooting by logging in through the browser and I can login perfectly well using both Facebook and Google.
2) I have added the internet permission in the manifest file.
3) I have also tried testing the app by changing the internet connections, in case it's a network connection problem but to no avail. I am able to login perfectly well through the browser on the same internet connection.

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: Have you registered your app with the providers?  Have you entered the provider settings in the portal's Identity tab?

Comment: Absolutely. That's why its working in the browser. Any other ideas? :(

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: The sample code found in the documentation is a little bit different.  Have you tried it? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-users/

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while when moving my working code over into a fresh app

It seems that after I eliminated the provider app connection as your problem (I used the javascript html client in parallel ) I needed to go back to basics because I found this similar question

[Check your Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358669/windows-azure-authentication-provider-is-not-enabled)

I also had this issue just happen on a successful build - the ADB bridge had failed and the emulator could not connect to the internet (I had switched networks)

This error code is not descriptive, but Azure seems to assume if it can't connect to a provider then you didn't set it up!